# How to select using a WHERE condition on an aliased column using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,users_codes.timestam,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 48,'no','yes') AS Expired
FROM users_codes
```

How do I return only rows that have `'no'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a `WHERE` condition. *You cannot use the `ALIAS` on the where clause*.

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,users_codes.timestam,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 48,'no','yes') AS Expired 
FROM   users_codes
WHERE  IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,users_codes.timestam,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 48,'no','yes') = 'no'
```

or use a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,users_codes.timestam,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 48,'no','yes') AS Expired 
    FROM   users_codes
) s
WHERE  Expired  = 'no'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do something like this

```
SELECT IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    HOUR,
    users_codes.timestam,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  ) < 48, 'no', 'yes') AS Expired

FROM users_codes
HAVING Expired = 'no';
```

Comment: well this works, but in `mysql` only. because you can't use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` clause.